# Are service workers ever removed automatically by the browser?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I've been trying to make PWAs that reliably work offline on and off for the past year, but every time I write a new service worker, it works as expected for a week or two and then just breaks (until reconnecting). I thought it was due to the site's data getting evicted, but the local storage is often intact when I reconnect to the internet so it can load. Recently I also had one of the service workers remain active, but its cache storage was deleted, as well as the other service workers (I've got multiple different sites on the same origin, some of which have service workers. It's my GitHub Pages).

According to the spec, it sounds like service workers should always remain registered unless the data for the whole origin is evicted. I also don't think my service workers are accidentally deleting their caches or unregistering themselves as the issue only happens after not using them for a while, in which case they aren't running. Clearing Chrome for Android's cache also doesn't break the PWAs when offline, so I don't think I'm manually doing anything that's breaking them. Clearing an individual PWA's storage and cache also doesn't break it.

The relevant sentence in the spec:

> "A user agent must persistently keep a list of registered service worker registrations unless otherwise they are explicitly unregistered."

(the unregistered service workers also don't show up in chrome://serviceworker-internals/ )

Any ideas? Do you think this is a bug? I've mostly seen this in Chrome for Android, but I think I'll try some other browsers as well to check. Unfortunately I can't test any of this very well as it's quite unpredictable and takes weeks.

These are the 2 main sites to try, as I use the same template for a few, although I don't think it'll be that helpful:

- https://hedgehog125.github.io/Bagel-PWA/
- https://hedgehog125.github.io/Bagel-V2/ see https://github.com/hedgehog125/SvelteKit-Plugin-Versioned-Worker/blob/main/src/worker.js for the proper service worker template

Thanks for any input

Edit: I thought it would be worth a try to see if that first site still works in Firefox while offline. It does, despite not visiting it in Firefox for maybe 6 months. I guess this is a Chrome bug/feature then?

Edit: Updated the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

7 months later and I finally have somewhat of an answer...

[The browser keeps them more-or-less forever](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/security/service-worker-security-faq.md), in the same way it does with IndexedDB. The same is also true with resources stored with the Cache API, which has a similar bit in the spec:

> "The Cache instances are not part of the browser’s HTTP cache. The Cache objects are exactly what authors have to manage themselves. The Cache objects do not get updated unless authors explicitly request them to be. The Cache objects do not expire unless authors delete the entries. The Cache objects do not disappear just because the service worker script is updated. That is, caches are not updated automatically. Updates must be manually managed. This implies that authors should version their caches by name and make sure to use the caches only from the version of the service worker that can safely operate on."

Since getting a new phone and not encountering the issue, I suspect it's to do with the amount of available storage. Either what's happening is:

- Chrome is breaking the spec and clearing certain parts of the site's storage, rather than evicting everything.
- Some program is trying to be helpful by deleting this cache. But I don't think I installed an app that would do that and it seems unlikely that there's a preinstalled app that would do it.

Looking at those, I'd say the 1st is more likely, but it still doesn't make much sense. Surely there are many more sites to delete the data of first. Maybe  Chrome has a process that clears *just* the cache storage when the device is running low? In any case, I'd probably have to read through the source code to find out.

I guess I'll also have to see if the issue reoccurs if and when I start to run out of storage on my new phone.